# Cannot change font in Opera/Webkit/IE via HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, font-face

I have an issue in which I have selected a font from Google Web Fonts and implemented it with HTML and in a seperate style-sheet respectively:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Body {font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;}
```

Effectively I have just followed the Web Fonts instructions. It works well in firefox but not any of the other browsers. Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing [this chart on `@font-face` browser support](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support), Webkit/Safari and Opera browsers do not support the WOFF font format, which is the format that particular font is in. Also, WOFF format is only supported in IE versions 9 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

the google docs [What browsers are supported?](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/faq.html#Browsers_Supported)

```
The Google Web Fonts API is compatible with the following browsers:
```

- Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+
- Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+
- Apple Safari: version 3.1+
- Opera: version 10.5+
- Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+

If someone using an unsupported browser visits a page that uses the Web Fonts API, then the text is displayed using the next available font in **your** CSS font stack.

Comment: Given that it is supported by Opera 10.5+, I have tested it only tested it on Opera 11.52 so far - so it should work, but doesn't.

Comment: just a heads up, ive tested it on opera 10.62 on winXP and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in my browser and it is working in the following browsers.

IE 8, Chrome 15.0.+, FF 7.0, Safari 5

Also I have noticed that the Google API will work in the following browsers.

The Google Web Fonts API is compatible with the following browsers:

- Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+,
- Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+,
- Apple Safari: version 3.1+,
- Opera: version 10.5+,
- Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+

Hope you are testing with the above mentioned browsers.

Thank You